Can my HC-05 bluetooth module pair with my computer's bluetooth?
I use my HC-05 module for remote connection but I only have one. So I want to connect it to my computer which does color recognition. I could pair with my computer but I cannot see virtual serial port. I try setiing the module to be different modes but still cannot work. And I find it will always return fail if I try change the password. The board I use is stm32G431
Sorry for the unclear expression beacause of my poor English.
I can use UART and ttl to USB module to communicate with HC-05 module. And it can connect to the bluetooth of my mobile phone successfully. The AT mode also works. But I want it to communicate with my PC, how can I make it?

Yes, it can be paired with PC. If OS support such feature it may (or may not) to create vCOM for your HC-05 when paired. But Bluetooth does not require COM port so it is up to OS. For example, on Windows you can pair with Bluetooth device that supports Serial Port Profile and then Windows may create vCOM for such device.
